# how to play a video in fullscreen mode using swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I've a `url  = http//www.dd.com/mysong.mp4`, and I've a `UIView controller` in portrait mode of iphones using `Auto layout and size classes`. and I need to rotate the viewController and then play my video in fullscreen. because I cant use `orientation`, cause `constraints` wont support. it is  `Compact and regular size class`.  how to play video in fullscreen using `AV PLAYER`.  Atleast help me with playing video in fullscreen what ever the things may be? Any related stuff Please

Comment: Your app is in portrait view and you want video in landscape view? Plus your app supports landscape view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance of  and present it.

```
import AVKit

import AVFoundation

func playVideo(urlString: String) {

     guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
     let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
     let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
     playerViewController.player = player
    
     self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
        
        
     })
   }
}
```

Comment: subclassing AVPlayerViewController is not advised according to Apple.

Comment: @Raildex Can you share a link from apple docs?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller

Comment: Hmm, yeah it is right, but I can derived classes from AVPlayerViewController. Updating my answer though. @Raildex