# AVPlayer not full screen in landscape mode using iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer

I have a video view set to full screen. However while playing in the simulator, it is not running full screen.

This issue is only for iPads and not iPhones.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main
    let videoPlayer: String = bundle.path(forResource: "normalnewer", ofType: "mp4")!
    let movieUrl : NSURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: videoPlayer) as NSURL
    //        var fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Mantas/Desktop/123/123/video-1453562323.mp4.mp4")
    playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieUrl as URL)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,object: self.playerView.currentItem) // Add observer

            var playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: playerView)
//        self.avPlayerLayer.playerLayer = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill


    playerLayer.frame = viewVideo.bounds
//        self.playerLayer.frame = self.videoPreviewLayer.bounds

    viewVideo.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)




    playerView.play()

    UserDefaults.standard.set("normalnewer", forKey: "video")




}
```

I have tried checking landscape mode in target's general. 
Gone through the threads below:
[how to play a video in fullscreen mode using swift ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043205/how-to-play-a-video-in-fullscreen-mode-using-swift-ios)

[Play video fullscreen in landscape mode, when my entire application is in lock in portrait mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759996/play-video-fullscreen-in-landscape-mode-when-my-entire-application-is-in-lock-i)

[Setting device orientation in Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios)

But these did not resolve my issue. 
Here is a screenshot.
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Can somebody help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time taking a good look at the Storyboard, I tried changing the fill to Aspect fill & fit and that resolved the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I see you solved your issue, but I noticed you were using an AVPlayerLayer. The orientation rotation is handled with the AVPlayerViewController, but not with a custom view using a player layer. It is useful to be able to put the layer in fullscreen without rotating the device. I answered this question elsewhere, but I will put it here as well.

Transforms and frame manipulation can solve this issue:

```
extension CGAffineTransform {

    static let ninetyDegreeRotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 2))
}

extension AVPlayerLayer {

    var fullScreenAnimationDuration: TimeInterval {
        return 0.15
    }

    func minimizeToFrame(_ frame: CGRect) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: fullScreenAnimationDuration) {
            self.setAffineTransform(.identity)
            self.frame = frame
        }
    }

    func goFullscreen() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: fullScreenAnimationDuration) {
            self.setAffineTransform(.ninetyDegreeRotation)
            self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the frame of the AVPlayerLayer changes it's parent's frame. Save the original frame in your view subclass, to minimize the AVPLayerLayer back to where it was. This allows for autolayout.

IMPORTANT - This only works if the player is in the center of your view subclass.

Incomplete example:

```
class AVPlayerView: UIView {

    fileprivate var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    fileprivate var hasGoneFullScreen = false
    fileprivate var isPlaying = false
    fileprivate var originalFrame = CGRect.zero

    func togglePlayback() {
        if !hasGoneFullScreen {
            originalFrame = frame
            hasGoneFullScreen = true
        }

        isPlaying = !isPlaying
        if isPlaying {
            avPlayerLayer.goFullscreen()
            avPlayerLayer.player?.play()
        } else {
            avPlayerLayer.player?.pause()
            avPlayerLayer.minimizeToFrame(originalFrame)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is put this code
In viewDidLayoutSubviews and enjoy it!

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.playerLayer?.frame = self.videoPlayerView.bounds
    }
```