# Full Screen with AVPlayerLayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer, avkit

I have two views

One is container of AVPlayerLayer like this

```
containerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

and containerView has own auto layout about superview

```
self.view.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
```

so i override `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = containerView.frame
}
```

and second view is custom playback control view on containerView

```
containerView.addSubview(playBackControlView)
playBackControlView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
playBackControlView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
playBackControlView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
playBackControlView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

and there are several views like `UIButton`, `UISlider` etc

Here is my question

when i tapped one of buttons on `playBackControlView` which called `enlargeScreenButton` how can make my containerView, playBackControlView and AVPlayerLayer gonna be a full screen like landscape mode at once

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43445697/6727030) question already but only playerLayer changed, not whole view

(I will not device rotation)

I did many thing on Stackoverflow but they were fit on my case

if i transform some views are broken and if i change frame with `UIScreen.main.bounds` also it broke some views

Comment: I'm not saying you can't do what you're doing, but why not use [AVPlayerViewController?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller) It manages fullscreen for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create a PlayerView subclass with custom layer view as such:

```
class PlayerView: UIView
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

This way you'll be able to manipulate the view without caring about the sublayer and it's animation. Then you'd be able to use the animations similar to ones from the [answer you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43445697/6727030), but on the view. With all the subviews added using auto layout - you should be good to go and they should change accordingly when you animate using `UIView.animate`